# jQuery page redirection

Tags: jquery, redirect

I have a script that redirect a page using jQuery. I want it to redirect to a link specified in the a tag `<a href="delete.php?id=23"`. below is my code which redirect it to a fixed URL `http://localhost/Project1/delete.php`

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var site_url = 'http://localhost/Project1/delete.php';
    jQuery('#Delete').confirmOn({
        questionText: 'This action cannot be undone at a later time, are you sure?',
        textYes: 'Yes, I\'m sure',
        textNo: 'No, I\'m not sure'
    },'click', function(e, confirmed) {
        if(confirmed) window.location.href = site_url;
    });
});
</script>

<a href="delete.php?id=23" id="Delete" title="Delete This">Delete Me</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to get the `href` value of your anchor. So you can do:

```
var site_url = $('#Delete').attr('href'); // or .prop('href')
```

instead of:

```
var site_url = 'http://localhost/Project1/delete.php';
```